# Binding ToolbarItem Click in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build my first, simple application with Xamarin.Forms.

In this app I have a ContentPage with a ListView and a Toolbar (inside a NavigationPage).

The Toolbar has a ToolbarItem that should run a method when clicked. Even though I've searched Google thin, I simply can't get it to work...

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:FlashCards;assembly=FlashCards"
x:Class="FlashCards.SetsPage" 
Title="Card Sets">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
          <ToolbarItem Name="Add" Icon="Icon-Button-Add.png" Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ListView x:Name="CardSetView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

CodeBehind:

```
//...
public partial class SetsPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<CardSet> sets = new ObservableCollection<CardSet>();

        public Command CreateCommand { get; private set; }

        public SetsPage() {

            InitializeComponent();

            sets.Add(new CardSet{ Title = "Test 1" });
            sets.Add(new CardSet{ Title = "Test 2" });
            sets.Add(new CardSet{ Title = "Test 3" });

            CardSetView.ItemsSource = sets;

            this.CreateCommand = new Command(async (sender) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
                });

        }
    }
//...
```

I've tried:

1. What you see above
2. Creating the toolbar *and* the button only through C# (And adding a `async () => { ... }` parameter to the ToolbarItem constructor)
3. A regular ol' `(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => { ... }` event listener (through code with `.Clicked +=`)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a binding context problem. If you have the command into a separate class (ideally a ViewModel) and use this as binding context for your page, then it should work as expected

```
public class MyVm {
    public MyVm() {
        this.CreateCommand = new Command((sender) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
        });
    }

    public ICommand CreateCommand { get; private set; }
}

...

public SetsPage() {
        var vm = new MyVm();
        this.BindingContext = vm;

        InitializeComponent();
...
```

Comment: alternatively, you could just set this.BindingContext = this;

Comment: that doesn't work as expected in my test. Did you try?